# Airflow ECSOperator Example

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-ecs

Has someone already implemented the ECSOperator in Airflow? I've searched and didn't find any example of use.

I've looked at the Github https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/tests/contrib/operators/test_ecs_operator.py but it seems confuse to me.

I already had the task running on CloudWatch.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm trying to use this version for ECSOperator: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.3post1/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/ecs_operator.html
It's not working still, I'm able to send a task for the ECSOperator although it does not complete the task that is supposed to do, and I'm not being able to see docker internal logs so I can debug. :'(

Warning: filter for your airflow version